# Python dictionary iteration insertion

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a dict concept;

```
for ind_list in reflist:
    for i in ind_list.attributes.keys():
        valueofKey = ind_list.attributes[i].value
        temp_dict[i] = valueofKey
```

I have this piece of code which adds values to a dictionary. But the problem is, after running this loop, I am only getting the last element inserted.

That means I am not inserting all the elements into the dict.
I have used update and append. Both does not work.
can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Show your full code, expected output and example data set please.

Comment: For "full code" read [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); enough that other users can try to duplicate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)
for ind_list in reflist:
    for key, val in ind_list.attributes.items():
        temp_dict[key].append(val.value)
```

Now each value in `temp_dict` is a `list` of all `val.value`s corresponding to the appropriate `key`.

Comment: Actually the above logic works in my code. I did a few tweaks, and it works the way i want.